# Unknown assertion failure in jenkins build

Tags: ios, jenkins, xcodebuild

I am at a loss, I simply do not see the problem...
We are using Jenkins build scripts which are all well and functioning, only one particular
build gives me a headache.

> ++ xcodebuild clean install -project /Volumes/Daten/Jenkins/workspace/HAGR/HAGR/HAGR.xcodeproj -sdk
>   iphoneos -configuration EnterpriseDistributionInHouse
>   'DSTROOT=/Volumes/Daten/deliverables/iOS/HAGR/1.0.2 (20130805.1)'
>   INSTALL_PATH=/EnterpriseDistributionInHouse
>   'DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH=/Volumes/Daten/deliverables/iOS/HAGR/1.0.2
>   (20130805.1)/EnterpriseDistributionInHouse' 'CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=iPhone
>   Distribution: apploft GmbH' '' -showBuildSettings
>   ++ cut -f2 -d=
>   ++ sed 's/^ *//' 2013-08-05 14:49:29.003 xcodebuild[64443:1207] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in
>   /SourceCache/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport/IDEXcode3ProjectSupport-2110/Xcode3Sources/XcodeIDE/Frameworks/DevToolsBase/pbxcore/Target.subproj/PBXTarget.m:1407
>   Details:  buildAction should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty
>   string Object:    Method:
>   -dynamicallyComputedTargetBuildSettingsWithAction:configurationName: Thread:   {name = (null), num = 1} Hints: None
>   Backtrace:   0  0x000000010a8a76b3 -[DVTAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:messageFormat:arguments:]
>   (in DVTFoundation)   1  0x000000010a8a74e4 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler
>   (in DVTFoundation)   2  0x000000010bab5cf9 -[PBXTarget
>   dynamicallyComputedTargetBuildSettingsWithAction:configurationName:]
>   (in DevToolsCore)   3  0x000000010bab63b8 -[PBXTarget
>   createPropertyExpansionContextWithBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore) 
>   4  0x000000010bbd186e -[XCTargetDGSnapshot
>   initWithInformationFromTarget:withBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore) 
>   5  0x000000010bbd5a7d -[XCNativeTargetDGSnapshot
>   initWithInformationFromTarget:withBuildParameters:] (in DevToolsCore) 
>   6  0x000000010bac1633 -[PBXTarget
>   createDependencyGraphSnapshotWithTargetBuildParameters:] (in
>   DevToolsCore)   7  0x000000010babdace -[PBXTarget
>   propagateTargetSnapshotIfNeededWithCompletionBlock:] (in DevToolsCore)
>   8  0x000000010bac1379 -[PBXTarget
>   createDependenciesInTargetBuildContextIfNeeded] (in DevToolsCore)   9 
>   0x000000010b0a0815 -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool _showBuildSettings]
>   (in Xcode3Core)  10  0x000000010b0a4ae1 -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool
>   run] (in Xcode3Core)  11  0x000000010a81d9a6 (in xcodebuild)  12 
>   0x000000010a81d770 (in xcodebuild)  13  0x000000000000000f

What exactly is the problem (because the command is working on other
projects) ? I tried clean install, remove all builds, check
the directory permissions....

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Well I keep seeing "Xcode3" which is a very outdated version of xcode.

Comment: Well jenkins is for some reason attempting to build with xcode 3. what is the output of `xcodebuild -version`

Comment: Still 4.6.3. There is no other version on the system, I simply assume that this XCode3 text is coming from something else

Comment: We'll maybe you should look into why that text says what it does. That May Lead to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The finally found reason is that innocent line:

GmbH' '' -showBuildSettings

The double quote '' is a remnant of an accidentally unset environment variable
which is filled correctly in the other cases.

Problem solved.

Comment: Surprisingly we had similar problem, one missing double quote :)